# SQLLDR Postition Relative to End of Line

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to load some data using SQLLDR into Oracle.  The data are in variable length lines.  I need to pull the first 9 characters into one column, and the last 8 characters into a second column.  Can I do this in SQLLDR directly or do I need to parse the data separately?

I was thinking something like:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
APPEND INTO TABLE trans_req
( student_id POSITION(1:9), 
  inst_id POSITION(-8:)
)
```

But I don't think that syntax is correct.  Also thought about using some SQL function to grab the end of the line, but wasn't sure if SQLLDR would grab everything to the EOL, or just enough characters to fill in the column (8).

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
APPEND INTO TABLE trans_req
( student_id POSITION(1:9), 
  inst_id POSITION(*) "SUBSTR(:inst_id, -8, 8)"
)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have variable-length lines but they aren't delimited? What's in between, and how sure are you that those two values will both always be populated? It might be clearer for you to load it as a single column in an external table and parse/translate/chop it up from there.

Comment: This is a data dump from another system, can't change format. No delimiters.  They send 9 columns/row but I only need the first and last.  All the data is fixed-length, but it's thrown off because some of their other cols(5, 6 and 7) can contain null values, which ends up taking no space in their data dump.  So for one line I might get the inst_id from position 100:108, the next line might have it at 92:100.  I was previously copying the data into excel and using LEFT and RIGHT functions to grab the data into two separate columns but this lets me avoid that extra step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second idea ended up working, here's the actual working syntax:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
APPEND INTO TABLE trans_req
( student_id POSITION(1:9), 
  inst_id CHAR(600) "SUBSTR(:inst_id, -8, 8)"
)
```